# Spiral loop for image pixel analyze (x,y) C#

Tags: c#, image, search, pixel, spiral

I'm trying to do a pixel search in coordinates (x,y)

I need something like a function(int width, int height) that returns an array of points starting from the center.

if image has 1000x1000, i need to get [{500,500}, {501,500}, {501,501}, {500,501}, {499,501}, {499,500} ...]

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: So, the offsets are x=1, y=1, x=-2, y=-2, x=3 ,y=3, x=-4, y=-4... pretty sure you can figure out the pattern from there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was easier than I thought it would be.

```
static IEnumerable<Point> GetPixels(int size)
{
    Point point = new Point(size/2, size/2);

    yield return point;
    int sign = 1;
    for (int row = 1; row < size; row++)
    {
        // move right/left by row, and then up/down by row
        for (int k = 0; k < row; k++)
        {
            point.Offset(sign*1, 0);
            yield return point;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < row; k++)
        {
            point.Offset(0, -sign*1);
            yield return point;
        }
        sign *= -1;
    }
    // last leg to finish filling the area
    for (int k = 0; k < size-1; k++)
    {
        point.Offset(sign*1, 0);
        yield return point;
    }

}
```

with the result (`size=5`)

```
{X=2,Y=2}
{X=3,Y=2}
{X=3,Y=1}
{X=2,Y=1}
{X=1,Y=1}
{X=1,Y=2}
{X=1,Y=3}
{X=2,Y=3}
{X=3,Y=3}
{X=4,Y=3}
{X=4,Y=2}
{X=4,Y=1}
{X=4,Y=0}
{X=3,Y=0}
{X=2,Y=0}
{X=1,Y=0}
{X=0,Y=0}
{X=0,Y=1}
{X=0,Y=2}
{X=0,Y=3}
{X=0,Y=4}
{X=1,Y=4}
{X=2,Y=4}
{X=3,Y=4}
{X=4,Y=4}
```

or graphically for `size=50`

[image: fig]

The test code is simple enough

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var point in GetPixels(5))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{point}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I even managed to do but your way is very better than mine.. Thanks!